# polygon split with predefined area

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer, polygon-creation

I am trying to split an irregular polygon into 120 equal area blocks. I also need a buffer around each new block within the polygon.

Is this possible in QGIS 2.12.1?

Comment: Any particular shape you want these blocks to be? I think I've already answered something similar where the shapes are slices, but easy enough to adapt to sectors from a central point. I think I did it using R's spatial overlay operators. Easy enough to implement in python. Can you program in python?

Comment: I need them to be rectangular and run parallel to a crop row. I am fairly new with the software so no I do not know how to program in python

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but there is the **Polygon Splitter** plugin which allows you to split a polygons into predefined equal parts in a vetical, horizontal (or a combination of both) fashion. You can download this from the toolbar:

*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...*

---

Example polygon:

[image: Example polygon]

Result:

[image: Split polygon]

---

Tested using QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon.