# Is there a way to split a shapefile into 10ha blocks?

Tags: qgis

I'm relatively new to QGIS and I'm trying to work out how to split a shapefile I have created into 10ha blocks in QGIS. The shapefile is a blob shape and not a rectangle/square so it can't just be a grid. The area is approximately 250ha in total.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [polygon split with predefined area](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185797/polygon-split-with-predefined-area). Not sure why your question is being voted to be closed as you quite clearly mentioned your shapefile is a "blob" (i.e. irregular) so using a grid will output unequal areas.

Comment: Most welcome, hope you get the results you're looking for =)